# TableView Muestra el último Registro en JavaFx

Tags: javafx

Tengo una tabla llamada *tbl_EstadosGen* que se carga de una base de datos que tiene 4 registros, pero la tabla me muestra el último registro repetido 4 veces. No logro identificar el inconveniente.
La primera vez que la cargué, mostró bien, pero cuando hice pruebas de agregar datos, eliminar datos y actualizar datos, ya no procesaba el cargue de los datos en la tabla. La idea es que, si inserto un dato, al finalizar la inserción se carguen los datos en la tabla y así para cada acción de insertar, actualizar y eliminar.

Código:

```
    //Constructor
        public EstadosDAO(int codigoEstado, String descripcionEstado) {
            this.codigoEstado=codigoEstado;
            this.descripcionEstado=descripcionEstado;
        }
    
    
    //CONTROLADOR
    @FXML
        public void cargartablaestados() {
            Statement st;
            String sql;
            try {
                estados.clear();
                Connection con = Conexion.conectar();
                sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_EstadosGen";
                st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    estados.add(new EstadosDAO(
                            rs.getInt("CodGen"),
                            rs.getString("DescEstGen")));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Cargar los Estados");
            }
        }
    
        public void configtablaEstados() {
           col_CodEst.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("codigoEstado"));
           col_DescEst.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("descripcionEstado"));
           tbl_Estados.setItems(estados);
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
            estados.clear();
            configtablaEstados();
            estados=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            tbl_Estados.setItems(estados);
            cargartablaestados();
        }
```

RESULTADO
[image: Resultado Obtenido]

VALOR BASE DE DATOS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar. El código lo modifiqué y después de asociar las columnas creé este código
Código.

```
public void rellenarTblEstados() {
    try {
        estados.clear();
        Conexion conexion =new Conexion();
        con= conexion.conectar();
        stm=con.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_EstadosGen");
        while (rs.next()) {
            estados.add(new EstadosDAO(
               rs.getInt("CodGen"),
               rs.getString("DescEstGen")));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }
    tbl_Estados.setItems(estados);
}
```

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Explica además qué cambios exactamente has hecho. Lee [answer].

Comment: lo que dijo padaleiana :)